# Plotting timedeltas in matplotlib, Python

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, timedelta

I'm not exprienced with date manipulations in Python so plotting timedeltas is obnoxious problem. 
I have a list of dates:

```
Time = ['2004-09-21 01:15:53', '2004-09-21 20:49:47', '2004-09-18 09:54:32',...]
```

Let's define:

```
def __datetime(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Then:

```
dates = [__datetime(x) for x in Time]
```

Now I can subtract dates:

```
delta = []
for i in range(0, 20):
    j = dates[i+1]-dates[i]
    delta.append(j)
```

delta looks like this:

```
[datetime.timedelta(0, 70434), datetime.timedelta(-4, 47085),...]
```

Alternatively, it can be respresented as:

```
delta = [k.__str__() for k in delta]
['19:33:54', '-4 days, 13:04:45', '775 days, 12:07:02',...]
```

My question is: How I can plot these deltas on yaxis and get sensible lables?